# Where/Case/IN logic

Tags: sql-server-2012, case, where-clause, any

I am writing code in SSMS using SQL Server 2012.
Is it possible to have a case statement in the where clause that is skipped under certain conditions?

For example this is what I tried 1st:

```
Where
    Case Substring(@@Servername,1,3)
        when 'BCR' Then SM.ItemCode in (1,3)
        When 'DCR' Then 'Some code to allow any Item Code'
        Else SM.ItemCode = 1
    End
    and SM.ItemDesc like '%Car%'
```

It does not like this code because the Case Statement can only return one value. Was my first thought after reading online. However when I remove the in (1,3) and make it just = 3. It says I have incorrect syntax near the = so it does not appear to like that either.

At which point I tried this:

```
Where SM.ItemCode in 
    (
    Case Substring(@@Servername,1,3)
        when 'BCR' Then 1
        When 'DCR' Then 'So code to allow any Item Code'
        Else 1
    End,
    Case Substring(@@Servername,1,3)
        When 'BCR' Then 3
        Else 1
    End
    )
    and SM.ItemDesc like '%Car%'
```

This appears to fix the issue of checking for two different Item codes at 'BCR' but I am unsure how to fix the issue at 'DCR' where it could be any Itemcode.

My newest thought was to add another Case like this:

```
Where 

Case SUBSTRING(@@Servername,1,3)
When 'DCR' then SM.ItemCode = any
Else
SM.ItemCode in 
    (
    Case Substring(@@Servername,1,3)
        when 'BCR' Then 1
        Else 1
    End,
    Case Substring(@@Servername,1,3)
        When 'BCR' Then 3
        Else 1
    End
    )
End
and SM.ItemDesc like '%Car%'
```

This however give the incorrect syntax near the = error still.

Comment: The result of a `case` expression is a value not more logic.

Comment: It would be helpful, if you could post what your data look like and what the expected result of your query would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do it like:

```
Where (
        (Substring(@@Servername,1,3) = 'BCR' and SM.ItemCode in (1,3)) or
        Substring(@@Servername,1,3) = 'DCR' or
        SM.ItemCode = 1
      ) and 
      SM.ItemDesc like '%Car%'
```

Comment: Thank you very much this worked exactly like I wanted it to. Grabbed both codes from BCR, every code from DCR and only code 1 from every where else

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be what you want:

```
where
    case substring(@@Servername, 1, 3)
        when 'BCR' and SM.ItemCode in (1, 3) then 42
        when 'DCR' then 42
        else case when SM.ItemCode = 1 then 42 else 0 end
    end = 42 and ...
```

To me that appears to be equivalent to:

```
where (
        SM.ItemCode = 1
    or  @@Servername like 'BCR%' and SM.ItemCode = 3
    or  @@Servername like 'DCR%'
    ) and ...
```

The results of the case expression is a "pseudo-boolean" not an ItemCode. The comparison after `end` is against our arbitrary "true" value, which could have been any other number we wanted. The result is just to flag cases that should be considered a pass. Sometimes this construction is useful but probably not here. I included it to see how to fix the query in your original line of thinking and show that you were fairly close to a solution.

Comment: Your second part would work just like the other answer I did use. However I did not notice it at first I looked at the first part which looked like it would not work for DCR. But thanks for the help

Comment: And why doesn't `when 'DCR' then 1` do what you wanted? I'm trying to help you understand how `case` works.

Comment: Because when 'DCR' I need it to equal every number. It should equal 1, equal 2, equal 3... For every number there is.